# SVN modules for Apache 2.4.2 HTTP server

Tags: apache

Which SVN binaries support Apache 2.4.2 HTTP server?

Because I got an error on loading modules for SVN modules such as mod_dav_svn.so and mod_authz_svn.so.

Currently I am using Apache 2.4.2 with SVN 1.7.6 modules.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working on Windows with the binaries from Apache Haus:

https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx#MODULES24

Anyway, the error could be because of a missing library in the Apache bin folder.

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
yum install mod24_dav_svn
```

See forum post *[mod_dav_svn for apache 2.4](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=688549)*.